# SignalR + AG-Grid AngularJS gridoption api is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, signalr, ag-grid

I am using SignalR with AngularJS Ag-Grid. Whenever there is a broadcast to the client I am updating the rows of my grid.

```
 hub.client.Update = function (response) {
           if (response) {
               var positionsResponse = angular.fromJson(response);
               $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                   $scope.response = angular.fromJson(positionsResponse.GridData);
                    $scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData($scope.response);
               });

           }
       };
```

In the setRowData line, I am getting an error that api is undefined. gridOptions is populated correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I sure wish there was an answer for this one.

Answer (score 1):

---

Is the error appearing in the console on page load, even when the grid is populating correctly? I was experiencing the same issue when trying to refresh the grid from a $http post. In the end it was due to my specifying ng-controller in more than 1 nested div:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
         <div ag-grid="gridOptions" class="ag-fresh" style="height:100%;" ng-controller="ctrl"></div>
</body>
```

By specifying it only once it resolved itself:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
       <div ag-grid="gridOptions" class="ag-fresh" style="height:100%;"></div>
</body>
```

Don't know if this'll help, but thought I'd share.

/j